# Clear the fault LED on an IBM x3650 M4 after accidental disk insertion and removal?

Tags: hardware, hard-drive, ibm, ibm-xseries

The server had a disk added, and then the operator realized they put the disk in the wrong server, so they pulled it out again. No harm done, the server is running and the disk was never actually accessed from the OS, but the Fault LED went on, and the IMM (Integrated Management Console) shows this "Active Event":

> The Drive 5 has been removed from unit disk or disk bay 5.

Since we don't need the drive (and indeed don't have it anymore), we want to clear this alert. I've tried clearing the event log, and it did remove the "disk inserted" and "disk removed" events, but neither the Fault LED nor the "Active Event".

How can I clear the Fault LED and tell the server to just accept that there is no disk in bay 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the alert (and the LED) cleared after a reboot of the IMM and a reboot of the server. Which of these was the "solution" I don't know, we just happened to need to do both at about the same time.

Comment: Glad you resolved this. Please be sure to [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able. There's even a [badge for self answering](http://$SITEURL$/help/badges/14/self-learner).

Answer (score 0):

Are the Drive 5 member of your raid configuration? If yes, u can import the foreign config on that hard drive. There are 2 method, 1st Boot into the raid controller web bios utility. 2nd using Megaraid Storage Manager on ur OS (u have to install it 1st).

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of accidents(the removing and reinstalling of hardware) it would definitely put the amber state on the Fault LED. A fix would be turning the server off again, remove the HDD and reinstall it properly then turning it on again.

The initialization of the server upon bootup will "refresh" the states of the hardware components and would therefore remove the amber state of the Fault LED, given that the disks are not defective or any other hardware issues are not present.

Also note that sometimes improper shutdown of servers on bootup will cause the Fault LED to be in the amber state.
This is because the initialization process(when the power button led flashes very fast) is not finished properly.
When this happens, the Fault LED will display the amber state because it can't recognize or "think" that a certain hardware component is installed.

a proper shutdown from the OS and server and a proper initialization would normally fix this.

Sometimes the IMM refresh also does the fix.

if the improper shutdown problem occurs and the Fault LED is still up, check your other components, they may have been damaged or something. :)

Comment: The "accident" was the exact *opposite* of what you describe.